# Add autoplay to youtubevideo

Tags: jquery, youtube, autoplay

I have a youtubevideo in a lightbox that is hidden on pageload and shows up on the click on a button. I do not want the video to start on pageload, therefore I do not set autoplay=1.

I want the video to start when the lightbox is shown. That is when visitors click on a button.

Here my Youtubevideo:

```
<div class="st_youtube_video">  
<iframe>
        frameborder="0" 
        width="1680" 
        height="945" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-gVYLXVqQ2c&rel=0">
        allow="autoplay"
</iframe>
</div>
```

And here my jQuery:

```
    $('#button').click(function() {  
       $('.st_youtube_video').addClass('st_active'); 
       $(".st_youtube_video").attr('src', $(".st_youtube_video", parent).attr('src') + '&autoplay=1'); 
        }); 

$('.st_remove').click(function() {  
    $('.st_youtube_video.st_active').removeClass('st_active'); 
  });
```

There must be somewhere mistakes, but I do noot see them. Even after trying several possibilities my code does not work. Could somebody look at it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine except all element needs to be within the iframe tag.

You'll need to remove the ">" from the first iframe tag. Hope this helps.